# The argument type 'Product (where Product is defined in '...' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Product (where Product is defined in '...')

Tags: flutter, dart, error-handling

I am trying to create a form and add data from it to my server. And get this 'The argument type 'Product (where Product is defined in C:\Study\kursova_bd\lib\logic\classes.dart)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Product (where Product is defined in C:\study\kursova_bd\lib\logic\classes.dart)'.'

```
ElevatedButton(
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF613CEA),
                // backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFA2A6B1),

                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(40,20,40,20),
              ),
              child: const Text('SAVE CHANGES'),
              onPressed: () {
                if(_formKey.currentState!.validate()){

                  var newItem = Product(productId: 0, name: _name.text, dateOfReceipt: _dateOfReceipt.text, expirationDate: _expirationDate.text, amount: int.parse(_amount.text), price: double.parse(_price.text), madeOf: int.parse(_made_of.text), ownerId: 22);

                  print('${newItem}');

                  Processing.putProduct(newItem);

                  Navigator.pop(context);
                  //update page func
                  print('sent');
                }

              },
            ),
```

[here is my putProduct function]

```
  static Future<String> putProduct(Product product) async {
try {
  var map = product.toJson();
  map['action'] = 'ADD_ITEM';
  final response = await http.post(
      Uri.http('161.252.125.133', '/dbkursach/itemactions.php'),
      body: map); //instead of "localhost" input ur local IPv4
  if (200 == response.statusCode) {
    return response.body;
  } else {
    return 'error';
  }
} catch (e) {
  return 'error';
}
```

}

- I tried to put the constructor in the agrument

Comment: I notice one says `C:\study` and one `C:\Study`. I guess at some place you use the wrong "S"

Comment: Yes, thanks. It remains to understand what to do with it next. I changed the name of the folder a month ago. I tried to use flutter clean and invalidate caches in android studio but it did not help